# The second find mongo function return zero array

Tags: reactjs, meteor

userKisan.find returns zero element array if I replace it with imageDatadb(just to check) this work. I dont know what I am doing wrong here, related files are imported and in other page inserting of data at userKisan runs smoothly meaning code is working and I am sure data is there.

```
   ......
    import {imageDatadb} from '../api/imageData';
    import {userKisan}   from '../api/usersdb';

render() {
      console.log('docsReadyYet',this.props.imageData);
      let fileCursors = this.props.imageData;

        let display = fileCursors.map((img, key) => {
          console.log('aaaaa',img.kUserrId);

          let kdata = userKisan.find({ }).fetch(); // if i replace userKisan with imageDatadb this works
          console.log('kdata',kdata);

          return <div key={key}>
            <img src={img.imageData}/>
            {kdata}
          </div>
        })
      return (
        <div>
            <PrivateHeader title= 'All'/>
            {/* <image src=""/> */}
            {display}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

and the tracker is

```
export default withTracker( ( props ) => {
    const filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('All image data');
    const docsReadyYet = filesHandle.ready();
    const imageData = imageDatadb.find({}).fetch();

    return {
      docsReadyYet,
      imageData,
    };
  })(AllCustomers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new publish with `userKisan` and subscribe to that. When you try to find documents from `imageDatadb` they are available because you subscribed to them.